# easiest way to make a POST action to a URI

Tags: windows, http, command-line, powershell, http-post

I am on windows and What is the easiest and fastest way to make a POST action to a URI? Can I achieve this with command line or PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using **[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)**?

Explicit usage in your pespective is described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/149329).

*Sample POST usage below (extracted from the curl [manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)):*

```
curl -d "name=Rafael%20Sagula&phone=3320780" http://www.where.com/guest.cgi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. looks like the easiest way. but how do I get the response back with this code?

Comment: You could redirect the output using ">" into a file or a variable

Comment: I'll try that but I am now unable to find where the command line tool is on the web. I downloaded something but it ended up as source code. do u know where I can download that command line tool

Answer (score 5):

Powershell example:

```
 $c=New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
 $c.Add('param1','value1')
 $c.Add('param2','value2')
 $wc = New-Object system.net.webclient
 $d = $wc.uploadvalues("http://your.url",$c)
```

Comment: $d is a byte array containing the body of the response from the resource.

Answer (score 1):

This is now native for PowerShell since version 3.0:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -method POST -uri http://somewhere.com/rest/sample -body $content
```

Aliased to `iwr`, `wget` and `curl`.

Saves all of the headache of creating a `WebClient` object.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

> PowerShell 3.0 is integrated with Windows 8 and with Windows Server 2012. Microsoft has also made PowerShell 3.0 available for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1, for Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 1, and for Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1.